# Parsing complex json in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

Im trying to get the price of a stock qoute using json_decode and file_get_contents.
im trying to get the price with associative arrays but I get undefined index errors and quite frankly I am stuck.
my code:

```
  $jsondata =file_get_contents("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/wmt/quote?format=json");
  $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
  $list = $json['list'];
  $resource = $list['resources'];
  $resource = $resource['resource'];
  $fields = $resource['fields'];
  $price = $fields['price'];
  echo $price;
```

the JSON:

```
{
    list : {
        meta : {
            type : "resource-list",
            start : 0,
            count : 1
        },
        resources : [{
                resource : {
                    classname : "Quote",
                    fields : {
                        name : "Wal-Mart Stores, Inc. Common St",
                        price : "68.570000",
                        symbol : "WMT",
                        ts : "1440014635",
                        type : "equity",
                        utctime : "2015-08-19T20:03:55+0000",
                        volume : "16333364"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should be work,

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$resoureces=$json['list']['resources'];
foreach ($resoureces as $value) {
$price=$value['resource']['fields']['price'];
}
print_r($price);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all going wrong at the following line:

```
$resource = $resource['resource'];
```

At this point, `$resource` is already a non-associative array that you should just be looping through:

```
$resources = $list['resources'];

foreach($resources as $resource) {
    $name = $resource['classname'];
    $fields = $resource['fields'];
    $price = $fields['price'];
}
```

Comment: this answer causes undefined index errors on classname and fields. Thanks for the answer though.